# How to pass an array size as a template with template type?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, type-inference

My compiler behaves oddly when I try to pass a fixed-size array to a template function. The code looks as follows:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

template <typename TSize, TSize N>
void f(TSize (& array)[N]) {
    std::copy(array, array + N, std::ostream_iterator<TSize>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    int x[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    unsigned int y[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    f(x);
    f(y); //line 15 (see the error message)
}
```

It produces the following compile error in GCC 4.1.2:

> ```
> test.cpp|15| error: size of array has non-integral type ‘TSize’
> test.cpp|15| error: invalid initialization of reference of type
>   ‘unsigned int (&)[1]’ from expression of type ‘unsigned int [5]’
> test.cpp|6| error: in passing argument 1 of ‘void f(TSize (&)[N])
>   [with TSize = unsigned int, TSize N = ((TSize)5)]’
> ```

Note that the first call compiles and succeeds. This seems to imply that while `int` is integral, `unsigned int` isn't.

However, if I change the declaration of my above function template to

```
template <typename TSize, unsigned int N>
void f(TSize (& array)[N])
```

the problem just goes away! Notice that the only change here is from `TSize N` to `unsigned int N`.

Section [`dcl.type.simple`] in the final draft ISO/IEC FDIS 14882:1998 seems to imply that an "integral type" is either signed or unsigned:

> The `signed` specifier forces `char` objects and bit-fields to be signed; it is redundant with other integral types.

Regarding fixed-size array declarations, the draft says [`dcl.array`]:

> If the *constant-expression* (`expr.const`) is present, it shall be an integral constant expression and its value shall be greater than zero.

So why does my code work with an explicit `unsigned` size type, with an inferred `signed` size type but not with an inferred `unsigned` size type?

**EDIT** Serge wants to know where I'd need the first version. First, this code example is obviously simplified. My real code is a bit more elaborate. The array is actually an array of indices/offsets in another array. <del>So, logically, the type of the array should be the same as its size type for maximum correctness.</del> Otherwise, I might get a type mismatch (e.g. between `unsigned int` and `std::size_t`). Admittedly, this shouldn't be a problem in practice since the compiler implicitly converts to the larger of the two types.

**EDIT 2** I stand corrected (thanks, litb): size and offset are of course logically different types, and offsets into C arrays in particular are of type `std::ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: Well the first example compiles just fine with Microsoft compiler (2005).
Digital Mars complains about "Error: integral expression expected" in line "void f(TSize (& array)[N]) {"

Comment: Can you give an example where you absolutly have to use this first version?

Comment: In thread about destructor of basic types was affirmed that you can't call ~int directly, but inside a template doing typedef int MyType; calling ~MyType was legal. 
But I think the correct approach is to use size_t for the second parameter.

Comment: this is definitely interesting Konrad. comeau accepts that code, at least.

Comment: Serge, litb, please make your comments into answers so other people can find them more quickly (since I think they're relevant).
@xhantt: I'm not sure what the destructor has got to do with this. Nowhere in my function should a constructor for `TSize` be called (even implicitly).

Comment: "The array is actually an array of indices/offsets in another array. So, logically, the type of the array should be the same as its size type for maximum correctness." while i don't know why the error occurs, that statement is definitely wrong. the type of an array index is "ptrdiff_t"...

Comment: ... and is not dependent on the element-type of an array in some way. I've no idea what the type of an array dimension size is. i would suspect size_t though.

Comment: With gcc 4.3.2 I get internal compiler error, so I think this is a compiler issue. But I completely agree with @litb: your statement make no sense to me and size_t is perfectly appropriate here.

Comment: litb, thanks for the correction. You're of course right again. I wasn't thinking.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Hmm, the Standard says in `14.8.2.4 / 15`:

> If, in the declaration of a function template with a non-type template-parameter, the non-type template-parameter is used in an expression in the function parameter-list and, if the corresponding template-argument is deduced, the template-argument type shall match the type of the template-parameter exactly, *except that a template-argument deduced from an array bound may be of any integral type.*

Providing this example:

```
template<int i> class A { /* ... */ };
template<short s> void f(A<s>);
void k1() {
    A<1> a;
    f(a);    // error: deduction fails for conversion from int to short
    f<1>(a); // OK
}
```

That suggests that the compilers that fail to compile your code (apparently GCC and Digital Mars) do it wrong. I tested the code with Comeau, and it compiles your code fine. I don't think there is a different to whether the type of the non-type template parameter depends on the type of the type-parameter or not. `14.8.2.4/2` says the template arguments should be deduced independent from each other, and then combined into the type of the function-parameter. Combined with /15, which allows the type of the dimension to be of different integral type, i think your code is all fine. As always, i take the c++-is-complicated-so-i-may-be-wrong card :)

**Update**: I've looked into the passage in GCC where it spits out that error message:

```
  ...
  type = TREE_TYPE (size);
  /* The array bound must be an integer type.  */
  if (!dependent_type_p (type) && !INTEGRAL_TYPE_P (type))
    {
      if (name)
    error ("size of array %qD has non-integral type %qT", name, type);
      else
    error ("size of array has non-integral type %qT", type);
      size = integer_one_node;
      type = TREE_TYPE (size);
    }
  ...
```

It seems to have missed to mark the type of the size as dependent in an earlier code block. As that type is a template parameter, it is a dependent type (see `14.6.2.1`).

**Update:** GCC developers fixed it: [Bug #38950](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=38950)

Comment: I think that you are probably right. Thanks for looking up the relevant passage.

Comment: litb, have you filed a bug report or submitted a patch? This should probably be done. I admit freely that I am intimidated by the kraken GCC project and have no idea how to do either.

Comment: Konrad Rudolph, i thought i would leave the job for you so you can earn the fame, but if you don't have the time or don't want to do it, i'll do it. Just leave another comment in that case.

Comment: Re bugfix: This is totally cool! Is there a statistic of how many StackOverflow discussions resulted in bug fixes? I know of at least one other.