# Templated references to std::array not invoking SFINAE* in MSVC . Bug?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I ran across a problem upgrading templated array references to `std::array` where I had used this:

```
template<class T, int N>
void f(T(&a)[N]){/* do stuff */;}
```

This has worked in all compilers I have used so I just did this when changing to `std::array`

```
template<class T, int N>
void f(std::array<T,N>& a){/* do stuff */;}
```

And this worked fine on MSVC. But when I ran the code on other compilers it did not
The following code works in MSVC but not other compilers. See https://godbolt.org/z/d9cqWMeaM which fails to match because N must be `std::size_t`.

*This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21740896/c-template-parameter-deduction-for-stdarray-with-non-size-t-integer) indicates that SFINAE should apply. However, as noted in the comments and in spite of the that answer, SFINAE, typically applies to rejection of malformed declarations. This is a deduction failure.

Is MSVC's acceptance of this code a compiler bug? And is the `T(&a)[N]` where `int N` was used legal even though all compilers I've ever used had no problem at all?

This was somewhat annoying because some of the prior code used the fact N was signed in various places.

Comment: N should be `std::size_t N`, not `int`.

Comment: @Eljay That appears to be the case which is why I think MSVC has a bug since it doesn't complain, even with high warning level. As for the c array version, all compilers accept it. I can't find any specific doc that states it must be `size_t`

Comment: The size of an array has always been `std::size_t`: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.array#1.sentence-2  The same applies to `std::array`: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/array#overview-5

Comment: You have no SFINAE here. The problem is that compiler fails to deduce template arguments from function call.

Comment: @NathanOliver  Yes, I know that's the maximum size and the value is converted to `size_t`. Most c arrays I use are well under 2gb though and I've never seen template rejection of it. Where in the language is this required for c array templates as in the example?

Comment: I linked to them in my comment.  Both the size of a regular array, and the size parameter of a `std::array` have the type `std::size_t`.

Comment: Looks like I'm mistaken about c arrays.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/472750/4342498

Comment: @NathanOliver. Excellent! That explains why the templated c arrays had always worked. So it just looks like there's a bug in MSVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::array` `size_type` is [specified](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/array) as `std::size_t`.

GCC and Clang are right, template deduction should fail in this case, according to [[temp.deduct.type]/18](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct#type-18):

> If `P` has a form that contains `<i>`, and if the type of `i` differs from the type of the corresponding template parameter of the template named by the enclosing *simple-template-id*, deduction fails.
> . . .
>
> *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> template<int i> class A { /* ... */ };
> template<short s> void f(A<s>);
> void k1() {
>   A<1> a;
>   f(a);             // error: deduction fails for conversion from int to short
>   f<1>(a);          // OK
> }
> ```

Note: in C++11 this rule was a little more human-readable, see [here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.deduct.type#17).

So technically MSVC's acceptance of the code is a bug. I would report it to the vendor (Help -> Send Feedback -> Report a Problem).

Comment: Agree. When I code with max warnings and /permissive-, I expect the compiler to flag things like this without having to run the code through other compilers.